# Revoking grant hierarchy in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is it possible in MariaDB to revoke a user's privileges and in the same time the privileges of the users that he granted? I've tried so far things like

```
REVOKE SELECT ON mysql.sometable FROM 'user'@'%' CASCADE;
```

but I'm getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

No.

There no record of what that 'user' granted, so no way to "cascade".